# After 11.0 update, iphone changed the images size that it uses

Tags: ios, xamarin, mobile, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

In my resources folder I have icons @2x and @3x
The iphone 7 plus was using the @3x items, but I noticed, After the 11.0 update, the iphone 7 plus is using the @2x images now...And now the icons are small to it.
Does someone know if happend some change about images sizes after the update??
How can I work with it now if in the 10.3 it uses the @3x and 11.0 it uses @2x???
I am using xamarin.forms

Comment: Check the size constraints on images , i don't think there are relationships between image size and this update...

Comment: Really it's verry strange, but it used to work before the update, but I will check again..